# How to dynamically add input fields in form for FieldList [Flask]?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm designing a website with a form that allows the user to input stuff and add more input fields, it sort of works like those inputfields that you enter your skills with, soi you can add more skills if you have more. But I'm struggling to display more than one input fields with FieldList as it only shows the number of min_entries I set it, even when I copy and paste the html code it only accepts the first one.

forms.py (please focus on the contents for now)

```
class ExerciseForm(FlaskForm):
    exercise = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    testcase = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])

class AddTopicForm(FlaskForm):
    topicname = StringField('Topic Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=100)])
    contents = FieldList(StringField(validators=[DataRequired()]), min_entries=1, max_entries=20)
    exercises = FieldList(FormField(ExerciseForm), min_entries=0, max_entries=10)
    submit = SubmitField('Add Topic')
```

html (I have no idea how to add one, and how to make it work)

```
    <div class="addtopicform">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.topicname }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.contents }}
                </div>
                <button type="button" onclick="addsection()">Add Section</button>
            <script>

            </script>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {% for field in form.exercises %}
                        {{ field }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-btn">
                    {{ form.submit(class="btn") }}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

website.py (The best result is one data in contents, but obviously I want more)

```
@app.route("/addtopic/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addtopic():
    if 'AccountID' in session:
        form = AddTopicForm()
        if session["Type"] == "teacher":
            if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
                print("success")
                topicname = request.form['topicname']
                contents = form.contents.data
                exercises = form.exercises.data
                print(topicname)
                print(contents)
                print(exercises)
                return render_template('course.html', user=session['Name'], acctype=session["Type"])
            else:
                return render_template('addtopic.html', user=session['Name'], acctype=session["Type"], form=form)
        else:
            flash("Only teachers can access to this page", "failure")
            return render_template('course.html', user=session['Name'], acctype=session["Type"])
    else:
        flash('An account is needed to access courses', 'failure')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

PLease help me, I couldnt find any useful resources online as all of them assumed I already have a list or is using the input element instead of flask element, which doesnt work at all with flask forms

Comment: Are you looking for append_entry()? https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.FieldList.append_entry It appends an empty/defaulted entry at the end of the existing fields. You write : "all of them assumed I already have a list".  Well, an empty list still is a list. So use an empty list and follow those resources you have found. Or am I misunderstanding your issue?

Comment: I think you misunderstood, um imagine those websites like LinkedIn that lets you enter your skills in a input bx right? but they also have a button that let you type more skills with mroe input boxes, thats the thing I want